# Is it possible to change status bar icon color to white? Or is there a dark theme status bar? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, statusbar

In my app, I've changed the background color of the status bar to black with : `window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.black)` (And it works). But now, you can't see the status bar icons! And yes, I've heard of: `window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`, but that sets the background (of the status bar) to white and the status bar icons to grey. Is there a way to make the status bar icons white, whilst still having a black background? Or is there a dark theme for the status bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme, set `windowLightStatusBar` to false -- and you can also set your status bar color in the theme:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this code snippet if you want to change it programmatically without changing your theme:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (darkIcons) {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.windowSystemUiVisibility or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
    } else {
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = window.decorView.windowSystemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR.inv()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add boolean values for night and light in res/values
@bool/is_light_theme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).